# Nginx redirect to gitlab renders gitlab without any css styling and js scripts

Tags: nginx, gitlab

for the past 10 hours I am trying to fight with setting up gitlab with a standalone installation of NGinx. I've faced multiple different issues of which I think I was able to solve but now I have one last problem which is that the GitLab page loads without any css styling or javascripts.

I have went through 20 different tutorials, 20 different configurations and I still can't get it to work.

I have Ubuntu 22.04.

I have modified the gitlab.rb file:

```rb
external_url 'http://localhost:8080'
nginx['enable'] = false
web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
nginx['listen_port'] = 8080
nginx['listen_https'] = false
```

My gitlab file inside nginx/sites-available/:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name sub.mydomain.co.uk;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }

    location ~ ^/(assets/|uploads/|system/|\.well-known|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
        # Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
        expires max;
        access_log off;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name sub.mydomain.co.uk;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain.co.uk.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/mydomain.co.uk.key;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }

    location ~ ^/(assets/|uploads/|system/|\.well-known|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) 
    {
        # Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
        expires max;
        access_log off;
    }
}
```

nginx.conf file is currently default:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Browser Error Events:

- Failed to load resource: (X.css / X.js etc.) the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
- Third-party cookie will be blocked. Learn more in the Issues tab.
- The resource https://sub.mydomain.co.uk/assets/highlight/themes/white-1b0806cb2775fab529e835804dfb351a11dd641f48d830a28b4b37882174cc0c.css was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.